# What does $\hat{T}$ represent?

Tags: vector-analysis

I am looking at line integrals and work..

According to my notes:
$$\frac{\overrightarrow{R}}{dt}=\hat{T} \cdot |\frac{d\overrightarrow{R}}{dt}|=\hat{T} \sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2+z'(t)^2}$$

So,the work is given by the formula:
$$W=\int_A^B \overrightarrow{F}(s) \frac{d\overrightarrow{R}}{ds}ds=\int_a^b \overrightarrow{F}(s) \overrightarrow{T}\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2+z'(t)^2} $$

But... why is it like that: $\displaystyle{\frac{\overrightarrow{R}}{dt}=\hat{T} \cdot |\frac{d\overrightarrow{R}}{dt}|}$ ?

And what is $\hat{T}$ ? What does it represent?

Answer (score 3):

This is the unit tangent vector. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentVector.html) for some more information about it.  It is the unit direction vector of the tangent line to each point of the parametric curve $\vec{R}(t)$.

Comment: And...at which cases can the formula be used?

Comment: Anytime $||\vec{R}'(t)||$ is non-zero. (And, of course, assuming $\vec{R}(t)$ is differentiable.)

Comment: Ok...but I meant the formula $W=\int_a^b \overrightarrow{F}(s) \overrightarrow{T}\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2+z'(t)^2} $

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant the formula for $\hat{T}$.  Another way you can think of $\hat{T}$ is as $\hat{T}(t)=\frac{d\vec{R}}{ds}(t)$ where $\frac{ds}{dt}=||\vec{R}'(t)||$.  Then whenever $\hat{T}$ is defined, the formula holds.